# Getting attribute's value in Nokogiri to extract link URLs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

I have a document which look like this:

```
<div id="block">
    <a href="http://google.com">link</a>
</div>
```

I can't get Nokogiri to get me the value of `href` attribute. I'd like to store the address in a Ruby variable as a string.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

```
html = <<HTML
  <div id="block">
    <a href="http://google.com">link</a>
  </div>
HTML
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(html)
doc.xpath('//div/a/@href')
#=> [#<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x80887798 name="href" value="http://google.com">]
```

Or if you wanna be more specific about the div:

```
>> doc.xpath('//div[@id="block"]/a/@href')
=> [#<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x80887798 name="href" value="http://google.com">]
>> doc.xpath('//div[@id="block"]/a/@href').first.value
=> "http://google.com"
```

Answer (score 30):

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open("[insert URL here]"))
href = doc.css('#block a')[0]["href"]
```

The variable `href` is assigned to the value of the `"href"` attribute for the `<a>` element inside the element with id `'block'`.  The line `doc.css('#block a')` returns a single item array containing the attributes of `#block a`.  `[0]` targets that single element, which is a hash containing all the attribute names and values.  `["href"]` targets the key of `"href"` inside that hash and returns the value, which is a string containing the url.

Answer (score 24):

Having struggled with this question in various forms, I decided to write myself a tutorial disguised as an answer.  It may be helpful to others.

Starting with with this snippet:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'

html = <<HTML
<div id="block1">
    <a href="http://google.com">link1</a>
</div>
<div id="block2">
    <a href="http://stackoverflow.com">link2</a>
    <a id="tips">just a bookmark</a>
</div>
HTML

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(html)
```

### extracting all the links

We can use xpath or css to find all the  elements and then keep only the ones that have an `href` attribute:

```
nodeset = doc.xpath('//a')      # Get all anchors via xpath
nodeset.map {|element| element["href"]}.compact  # => ["http://google.com", "http://stackoverflow.com"]

nodeset = doc.css('a')          # Get all anchors via css
nodeset.map {|element| element["href"]}.compact  # => ["http://google.com", "http://stackoverflow.com"]
```

But there's a better way: in the above cases, the `.compact` is necessary because the searches return the "just a bookmark" element as well.  We can use a more refined search to find just the elements that contain an `href` attribute:

```
attrs = doc.xpath('//a/@href')  # Get anchors w href attribute via xpath
attrs.map {|attr| attr.value}   # => ["http://google.com", "http://stackoverflow.com"]

nodeset = doc.css('a[href]')    # Get anchors w href attribute via css
nodeset.map {|element| element["href"]}  # => ["http://google.com", "http://stackoverflow.com"]
```

### finding a specific link

To find a link within the `<div id="block2">`

```
nodeset = doc.xpath('//div[@id="block2"]/a/@href')
nodeset.first.value # => "http://stackoverflow.com"

nodeset = doc.css('div#block2 a[href]')
nodeset.first['href'] # => "http://stackoverflow.com"
```

If you know you're searching for just one link, you can use `at_xpath` or `at_css` instead:

```
attr = doc.at_xpath('//div[@id="block2"]/a/@href')
attr.value          # => "http://stackoverflow.com"

element = doc.at_css('div#block2 a[href]')
element['href']        # => "http://stackoverflow.com"
```

### find a link from associated text

What if you know the text associated with a link and want to find its url?  A little xpath-fu (or css-fu) comes in handy:

```
element = doc.at_xpath('//a[text()="link2"]')
element["href"]     # => "http://stackoverflow.com"

element = doc.at_css('a:contains("link2")')
element["href"]     # => "http://stackoverflow.com"
```

### find text from a link

And what if you want to find the text associated with a particular link?
  Not a problem:

```
element = doc.at_xpath('//a[@href="http://stackoverflow.com"]')
element.text     # => "link2"

element = doc.at_css('a[href="http://stackoverflow.com"]')
element.text     # => "link2"
```

### useful references

In addition to the extensive [Nokorigi documentation](http://nokogiri.org/), I came across some useful links while writing this up:

- [a handy Nokogiri cheat sheet](https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri/wiki/Cheat-sheet)
- [a tutorial on parsing HTML with Nokogiri](http://ruby.bastardsbook.com/chapters/html-parsing/)
- [interactively test CSS selector queries](http://try.jsoup.org/)

Answer (score 5):

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML("HTML ...")
href = doc.css("div[id='block'] > a")
result = href['href'] #http://google.com
```

Answer (score 1):

```
data = '<html lang="en" class="">
    <head>
    <a href="https://example.com/9f40a.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" /> link1</a>
    <a href="https://example.com/4e5fb.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />link2</a>
    <a href="https://example.com/5s5fb.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />link3</a>
   </head>
  </html>'
```

Here is my Try for above sample of HTML code:

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(data)
doc.xpath('//@href').map(&:value)
=> [https://example.com/9f40a.css, https://example.com/4e5fb.css, https://example.com/5s5fb.css]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
document.css("#block a")["href"]
```

where `document` is the Nokogiri HTML parsed.