# How to extract HTML links and text using Nokogiri (and XPATH and CSS)

Tags: css, ruby, xpath, nokogiri

*(Update: This answer is written from the point of view of Nokogiri, but it's also useful if you're looking for the XPATH or CSS syntax for specific queries.)*

I love Nokogiri -- it's a wonderful tool for extracting elements from XML and HTML documents.  Although the online examples are good, they mostly show how to manipulate XML documents.

How can you extract extract links and link text from HTML using Nokogiri?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

*This is a mini-example originally written in response to [Getting attribute's value in Nokogiri to extract link URLs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7107642/558639), extracted here in Community Wiki style for easy reference.*

Here are some common operations you might do when parsing links in HTTP, shown both in `css` and `xpath` syntax.

Starting with with this snippet:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'

html = <<HTML
<div id="block1">
    <a href="http://google.com">link1</a>
</div>
<div id="block2">
    <a href="http://stackoverflow.com">link2</a>
    <a id="tips">just a bookmark</a>
</div>
HTML

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(html)
```

### extracting all the links

We can use xpath or css to find all the `<a>` elements and then keep only the ones that have an `href` attribute:

```
nodeset = doc.xpath('//a')      # Get all anchors via xpath
nodeset.map {|element| element["href"]}.compact  # => ["http://google.com", "http://stackoverflow.com"]

nodeset = doc.css('a')          # Get all anchors via css
nodeset.map {|element| element["href"]}.compact  # => ["http://google.com", "http://stackoverflow.com"]
```

In the above cases, the `.compact` is necessary because the search for the `<a>` element returns the "just a bookmark" element in addition to the others.

But we can use a more refined search to find just the elements that contain an `href` attribute:

```
attrs = doc.xpath('//a/@href')  # Get anchors w href attribute via xpath
attrs.map {|attr| attr.value}   # => ["http://google.com", "http://stackoverflow.com"]

nodeset = doc.css('a[href]')    # Get anchors w href attribute via css
nodeset.map {|element| element["href"]}  # => ["http://google.com", "http://stackoverflow.com"]
```

### finding a specific link

To find a link within the `<div id="block2">`

```
nodeset = doc.xpath('//div[@id="block2"]/a/@href')
nodeset.first.value # => "http://stackoverflow.com"

nodeset = doc.css('div#block2 a[href]')
nodeset.first['href'] # => "http://stackoverflow.com"
```

If you know you're searching for just one link, you can use `at_xpath` or `at_css` instead:

```
attr = doc.at_xpath('//div[@id="block2"]/a/@href')
attr.value          # => "http://stackoverflow.com"

element = doc.at_css('div#block2 a[href]')
element['href']        # => "http://stackoverflow.com"
```

### find a link from associated text

What if you know the text associated with a link and want to find its url?  A little xpath-fu (or css-fu) comes in handy:

```
element = doc.at_xpath('//a[text()="link2"]')
element["href"]     # => "http://stackoverflow.com"

element = doc.at_css('a:contains("link2")')
element["href"]     # => "http://stackoverflow.com"
```

### find text from a link

For completeness, here's how you'd get the text associated with a particular link:

```
element = doc.at_xpath('//a[@href="http://stackoverflow.com"]')
element.text     # => "link2"

element = doc.at_css('a[href="http://stackoverflow.com"]')
element.text     # => "link2"
```

### useful references

In addition to the extensive [Nokorigi documentation](http://nokogiri.org/), I came across some useful links while writing this up:

- [a handy Nokogiri cheat sheet](https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri/wiki/Cheat-sheet)
- [a tutorial on parsing HTML with Nokogiri](http://ruby.bastardsbook.com/chapters/html-parsing/)
- [interactively test CSS selector queries](http://try.jsoup.org/)

Comment: This is the best Nokogiri post ever.